# Tighter clustering on a larger dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-science, knn, dimensionality-reduction

not sure if im asking this question in the correct place but anyway...

I have been using sci-kit learn package to perform dimensionality reduction on 2 different datasets, one is a large dataset with several thousand genes and the other is a smaller dataset with only the most relevant 50 genes as identified as professionals in the area my data is centered around.

Basically with nearly all dimensionality reduction techniques I am seeing that the smaller dataset gives a higher accuracy (as would be expected).

However whenever I perform LDA(Linear Discriminatory Analysis) I am seeing the opposite effect where the larger dataset has a higher accuracy (tighter clusters, higher purity and higher accuracy using KNN).

Do you guys have advice on ways I could check that I am not making an error or ways to investigate why this is happening?

Thanks :)

Comment: Hey, first of all it's not very clear what is the end point and what is the method to get to this end point. Seems like you want to perform dimension reduction and then clustering, and there's some reference you compare against.

Comment: Briefly, when you do dimension reduction, are the so called relevant features weighed heavily in the first few components? Maybe you can explain the full problem with the community that more familiar with what you are trying to analyze : https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com